# D3.js difference between 'd.value' and 'd[value]'

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

I am wondering if there is a difference in referring to an element's data through `d.value` and `d[value]`. I normally use the former, but in [this tutorial](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) the author uses `d[value]` to update `pie().value`.
Since I am trying to do exactly the same thing (i.e. on user's click change the data displayed) I wonder if I can use both or if each has specific characteristics.

```
//here is the code I am referring to, specifically line 4

function change() {
  var value = this.value;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  pie.value(function(d) { return d[value]; }); // change the value function
  path = path.data(pie); // compute the new angles
  path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d.value` is same as `d['value']`. But not same as `d[value]`. Here value is a variable.
So if `value = 'x'` Then `d[value]` means `d.x`

So try with `d['value']`